# draw arc on map with any projection

Tags: algorithm, math, geo

I want minimize of usage of projection function to draw arc on plane.

As input of algorithm I have:

- latitude and longitude of center `C`
- radius `R` (orthodromic distance)
- azimuth of begin of arc according to center `A1`
- azimuth of end of arc according to center `A2`
- projection function `proj` that take latitude longitude and give x and y on plane,
  this function is continuous and has derivative, and its derivative is continuous
- `proj^-1` function that inverse `proj`

Output: array of points x, y on plane such is that their original `lat, lon = proj^-1(x, y)` has orthodromic distance ~ `R` and azimuth lay between `A1` and `A2`.

In such algorithm I want reduce calls to `proj`.

At now I can only imagine such slow and not accurate algorithm:

```
P1 = direct geodetic problem(C, R, A1)
P1_plane = proj(P1)
P1_plane_shift = P1_plane.x + 1, P1_plane.y + 1
P1_shift = proj^-1(P1_plane_shift)
A1_shift = inverse geodetic problem(P1_shift)
dA = A - A1_shift
```

after that I run cycle from `A1` to `A2` with `dA` step using `direct geodetic problem` helper function.

Such algorithm have such disadvantages:

1. Not accurate, because of angle error of `proj` may change from area near `P1` to area near `P2 = direct geodetic problem(C, R, A2)` [Never see this problem on real-life map projections and with `R` < 100 kilometer]
2. Call `proj` to often, so drawing works to slow for me

Any thoughts of improvements of this algorithm?

**Update** here is plot of possible input:
[image]

Comment: A picture of all this would probably help prevent misunderstandings.

Comment: @BitTickler I update my post and add picture

Comment: Given, that in your drawing R is the same for CP1 and CP2, I assume you use a sphere, not an ellipsoid model, right? And your plane is defined by the 3 points C, P1,, P2?! If both holds, all you want is draw an arc. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm (Bresenham arc algorithm) for a solution.

Comment: @BitTickler It is just example, where `proj` is good enough for area around `C`, `P1` and `P2`, but it may be that `|proj(P1)-proj(C)| - |proj(P2)-proj(C)}` > 1 kilometer, in other words on 3D space it is part of circle but after mapping to plane with deformation it become not circle, and problem to approximate this curve with calculation of minimum points, not to draw circle on plane.